# How to Upload Image from Camera to Server instead of image chooser

Tags: android, image-uploading

How can i upload images from camera to my web server ,

I was able to upload using image chooser like in this tuto

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/

, but i would like to choose images from camera and galery instead

```
    public void uploadMultipart() {


        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(filePath);

        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    //method to show file chooser
    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    //handling the image chooser activity result
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also found this method , but it didn't work for me

How can replace the file chooser method in the above code properly to get the image path and name , and then upload it as in the tuto

```
private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(UploadImageTest.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Uploading a captured image to the server the whole your code remains the same you just need to pass your captured image file path into your `uploadMultipart` function.

You will get captured image file path in your `onActivityResult`.